# Azure CosmosDb stored procedure select query from string array

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing an SP to delete some records. So i need to fetch the records which record ids are passed as string array.

```
function DeleteFn(email, docs) {
var container = getContext().getCollection();
var containerLink = container.getSelfLink();

var documentQuery =
{
    'query': 'SELECT * FROM c where c.email = @email and ARRAY_CONTAINS(@arr, c.id) ',
    'parameters': [{ 'name': '@email', 'value': email }, { 'name': '@arr', 'value': docs }]
};

container.queryDocuments(containerLink, documentQuery,
    function (err, items) {
            items.forEach(element => {
                container.deleteDocument(element, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

where email = 'test@test.com' and docs = ["doc1","doc2"]

am getting parse error for JSON.Parse(docs).

How to execute this or any better approach to direct delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of method `deleteDocument` should be documentLink. So you need to change your code to this:

```
container.deleteDocument(element._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions)
```

Then, if you pass your record ids as type String, you need to change your code like this:

```
'parameters' : [{'name':'@email', 'value':email}, { 'name': '@arr', 'value': JSON.parse(docs) }]
```

[image]

If you pass your record ids as type Custom, your code can work fine.

```
'parameters': [{ 'name': '@email', 'value': email }, { 'name': '@arr', 'value': docs }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but for the json parse am getting this for exactly the same described above  JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:1

Comment: Can you show me your screenshot of input parameters when you execute SP? I have tested it on my side, it can work fine.